# Multithreading two functions

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have two function, one called connect() and is used to login to my account and another called identify_2bgval() which grabs some data from my account.Since its a very long proccess i tried to use multithreading.

My question is: Can i use these two functions simultaneously?
I have thought to create a new function and then use Threads.Is it gonna work?Also, can i use double targets with the Thread() function?

```
run_together():
 connect()
 identify_2bgval()
Thread(target= run_together).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **identify_2bgval** does not depend on **connect** you can run it in a different thread

```
def run_together():
    t = Thread(target=identify_2bgval)
    t.start() #2nd thread
    connect() # main thread waits here ...
    t.join() # wait for the 2nd thread ...

#call it ...
run_together() #blocks until finished ...
```